# How to completely utilize GPU to reduce training time of a Keras CNN model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am training a simple Keras dog-cat image classifier with Tensorflow (GPU version) as backend.

GPU utilization is not crossing 40%. How can I increase the GPU utilization to reduce training time?

When we use CPU for training, almost 99% of CPU will be utilized in total. But why is GPU utilization not crossing 40% and training time is reduced?

This is my code for the classifier. Each epoch is taking 25 minutes in my system with Nvidia Geforce 940M GPU:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D,MaxPooling2D,Dense

from keras.layers import Flatten

#initialising the CNN
classifier = Sequential()

#step1 = convolution
classifier.add(Convolution2D(filters=32,
                 kernel_size=(3,3),
                 input_shape=(64,64,3),
                 activation='relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dense(128,activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))

classifier.compile(optimizer='adam',
           loss='binary_crossentropy',
           metrics=['accuracy'])


from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set',
                         target_size=(64,64),
                         batch_size=32,
                         class_mode='binary') 

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/test_set',
                        target_size=(64, 64),
                        batch_size=32,
                        class_mode='binary')

classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
             steps_per_epoch=8000,
             epochs=25,
             validation_data=test_set,
             validation_steps=2000)
```

Comment: Your model has very few layers, so there is not a lot of work for the GPU to do for each batch of data. This can be one reason why you are not seeing higher GPU utilization.

Comment: Yes I agree, but its taking 25 minutes for training each epoch.
Does it normally take that much time for such a simple model?